# Javascript function call giving unexpected weird results.

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, function, modal-dialog

I am developing a board game using `nodejs` and `socket.io`

I have a `board.html` file where there is a board, chat frame and game stats. The board has three layers First is board canvas (`z-index:0`), pawn's canvas (`z-index:1`) and (initially hidden, `z-index:2`) `iframe` which pops up a [modal](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp) when there is something to show to the user.

I added a button [show card] to the `board.html` file and made a `modal.html` file which contains only the modal. Whenever user clicks the button, `showCard()` function is called and the `modal.html` file is set to the iframe which pops up the modal. In my `modal.html` file I have a code which removes the modal if user clicks outside the modal. Upto this moment everything is working, now I again called the `showCard()` function after the modal is removed when user clicks outside the modal.

The code for **when user clicks outside the modal.**

```
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none"; //Removes the modal, works!
        showCard(); //After this call the function is being called but somehow the modal is not showing up again.
    }
};
```

**Problem:** I expected that the modal will be removed and it will be shown again. But somehow it is only getting removed. The `showCard()` function is getting called, but the modal is not showing up again.

The `showCard()` function:

```
function showCard(){
    document.getElementById("cardframe").style.display = "";
    document.getElementById("cardframe").src = "modal.html";
}
```

For debugging purpose I added an alert message on the first line in the `showCard()` function. Now, when I click on the button, first the alert is shown and then the modal is shown. Then when I cancel the modal by clicking outside the modal, the alert is show again (confirming showCard() function was called) but the modal doesn't show up.

I really can't understand why the same piece of code is showing the modal once and not again.

I have the code on github [here](https://github.com/srujan7/Masti---The-life-simulation-game) (let me commit and push now) if in case anybody wants to have a look at it.

*Feel free to suggest edits. Comment if anything is unclear.*

Answer (score 0):

When you call `showCard()` a second time, it is executed quite alright: the **iframe** shows up and **modal.html** is loaded, but your modal's **div** with `id="myModal"` (from your GitHub code in modal2.html) is still hidden so nothing is displayed:

```
modal.style.display = "none"; //Removes the modal, works!
```

The best solution (i think) would be to hide and show only the **iframe** with `id="cardframe"`.

Comment: I removed that `modal2.html` from my project yet the same problem!

Comment: @SrujanBarai That's not the problem Bro! The issue is that your iframe opens up but your modal doesn't show. This is because it is hidden by css the first time you close it. your `div` (with `id="myModal"`) is hidden so when you reopen the iframe with `showCard()`, nothing shows up. So instead of hiding the modal, hide the iframe that shows the modal. I can do a plnkr example if you still don't get what i'm saying.

Comment: Got you. Will give it a try and revert

Comment: Well, I forgot to mention, I did try this before as well. But that frame doesn't seem be accessible from my modal.html page. My frame is transparent but I can see its border. If I hide it from modal.html file, the border is still seen, meaning its still there. It seems to be a problem of accessibility. Not sure if this is the right work for JS as it is for JAVA.

Comment: Hmm...you should try putting the `iframe` in your app's main file  so that you can just control it from there. Alternatively, consider including your modal in the html page where it should popup. Then you can `hide` and `show` it easily with js.